# retrofit2 sending a PUT request method is wrong for PHP

Tags: php, android, put, retrofit2, http-put

I am trying to send a PUT request method from my Android app to my PHP endpoint but in my endpoint the PUT request is not recognized as a PUT request so I return **Request method is wrong!** message from my endpoint.

### Android interface and request execution

#### Interface for activation

```
@PUT("device/activate.php")
Call<DeviceRegistry> registryDevice();
```

#### Executing the request

```
DeviceRegistryAPI registryAPI =
            RetrofitController.getRetrofit().create(DeviceRegistryAPI.class);

Call<DeviceRegistry> registryCallback = registryAPI.registryDevice();

response = registryCallback.execute();
```

With this I am expecting a response but I am getting my endpoint error message.

---

### My PHP endpoint

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "PUT"){
   //doing something with the data
} else {
    $data = array("result" => 0, "message" => "Request method is wrong!");
}
```

I don't know why the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "PUT"` is false but I wonder if I am missing something on Retrofit 2.

---

### More Info.

I am using Retrofit2.

---

### Update 1: Sending json into the body

I am trying to send a json using the body.

It is my json:

```
{
    "number": 1,
    "infoList": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "info": "something"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "info": "something"
        }   
    ]
}
```

There are my classes:

```
class DataInfo{

    public int number;  
    public List<Info> infoList;

    public DataInfo(int number, List<Info> list){
        this.number = number;
        this.infoList = list;
    }
}


class Info{
    public int id;
    public String info;
}
```

I changed the PUT interface to this:

```
@PUT("device/activate.php")
Call<DeviceRegistry> registryDevice(@Body DataInfo info);
```

But I am getting the same problem.

---

### Update 2: Do I need Header

I have this header in my REstfull client:

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Do I need to put this on my request configuration? How do I do that if I need it?

### Update 3: checking the request type of my sending post.

Now I am checking the type of the request. Because I am having the same problem with the PUT/POST requests. So If can solved the problem with the put maybe all the problems will be solved.

When I execute the request and asking and inspect the request it is sending the the type (PUT/POST) but in the server php only detect or GET?? (the below example is using **POST** and the behavior is the same)

```
Call<UpdateResponse> requestCall = client.updateMedia(downloadItemList);
Log.i("CCC", requestCall .request().toString());
```

And the output is a POST:

```
Request{method=POST, url=http://myserver/api/v1/media/updateMedia.php, tag=null}
```

so I am sending a POST (no matter if I send a PUT) request to the sever but why in the server I am receiving a GET. I am locked!!! I don't know where is the problem.

### Update 4: godaddy hosting.

I have my php server hosting on godaddy. Is there any problem with that? I create a local host and everything works pretty good but the same code is not working on godaddy. I did some research but I didn't find any good answer to this problem so Is possible that godaddy hosting is the problem?

Comment: return `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to the client and see what is the request method

Comment: @shayanpourvatan I did it, but the server return **GET**, I don't know why?

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't recognize anything other than GET and POST. the server should throw at you some kind of error like empty request.

[To access PUT](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php) and other requests use

```
$putfp = fopen('php://input', 'r'); //will be a JSON string (provided everything got sent)
$putdata = '';
while($data = fread($putfp, filesize('php://input')))
    $putdata .= $data;
fclose($putfp);
//php-like variable, if you want
$_PUT = json_decode($putdata);
```

did not tested, but should work.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that you don't pass any data along with `PUT` request, that's why PHP recognizes the request as a `GET`. So I think you just need to try to pass some data using `@FormUrlEncoded`, `@Multipart` or probably `@Body` annotations

Comment: I changed the request but the problem is the same. I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Hm... I'm not an expert in PHP, but could it cause the problem that you use double quotes instead of single for method type? I mean maybe you should change condition to the following: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT'`.

Comment: I did a test sending back the result of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`  and its value was `GET`. So I think that the problem is with retrofit2, well no with retrofit2 but with my configuration. I don't know if I need to send or configure something else. I am locked here.

Comment: Maybe you did that test before you've changed your Android code to the latest, which passes some data in `PUT` request?

Comment: Do you have any piece of code that uses retrofit2 and send a PUT/POST request? I am pretty sure that I am doing something wrong or missing something in the request configuration but I don't know what. I keep searching.

Answer (score 1):

To add header in your retrofit2 you should create an interceptor:

```
        Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException
            {
                okhttp3.Request.Builder ongoing = chain.request().newBuilder();
                ongoing.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                ongoing.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

                return chain.proceed(ongoing.build());
            }
        };
```

and add it to your client builder:

```
        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        builder.interceptors().add(interceptor);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. PHP recognises 'PUT' calls. Extracted from [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> 'REQUEST_METHOD' Which request method was used to access the page;
>   i.e. 'GET', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'PUT'.

2. You don't need to send any header if your server isn't expecting any
   header.

Prior to use Retrofit or any other networking library, you should check the endpoint using a request http builder, like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com) or [Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo). To debug the request/response when running your app or unit tests use a proxy like [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com), it will help you a lot to watch how your request/response really looks.